# What does "chainable" in context of testing (mocha, chai) mean?

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, chai

I am new to JavaScript and testing. Only recently I wrote a test for the first time in my life. I am refering to "Chai.js" documentation and it says:

> The assert style is very similar to node.js' included assert module,
>   with a bit of extra sugar. Of the three style options, assert is the
>   only one that is not chainable. Check out the Style Guide for a
>   comparison.
>
> The BDD styles are expect and should. Both use the same chainable
>   language to construct assertions, but they differ in the way an
>   assertion is initially constructed. Check out the Style Guide for a
>   comparison.

what does "chainable language to construct assertions" mean? 
Here is an [example](https://github.com/sindhus/scrollback/blob/d958a3f7c20dbce8d7040b9c6dd266a14bdb7675/test/public/t/integration/room-back-away-join-part-test.js) of the test file I wrote.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expect/should asserts in `chai` can be chained on top of each other in what looks like a single statement. In the following example, first you execute an assert on an object and then on a property of the object which becomes the context of chaining after the first assert:

```
expect({ foo: 'baz' }).to.have.property('foo')
  .and.not.equal('bar');
```

If you want to do the same with assert you would have to accomplish it in two different asserts and one would be executed on the object and the other on the property of the object:

```
var foo = { foo: 'baz' };
assert.property(foo, "foo", "object does not contain a foo property");
assert.notEqual(foo.foo, "bar", "The foo property is equal to 'bar'");
```